# Wrap method calls in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I would like the following method call to wrap to column 80

`Block testBlock = new Block(new Point(0, 0), new Point(8, 8), 0, null);`

Most of my other wrapping works but I can't make this one work. However, if I manually wrap it, and then run 'Reformat code', nothing happens to this line.
Another example of incorrect wrapping is the following:

`botLeftTree = createChild(leftX, midY, midX, botY, depth() + 1, this);`

Answer (score 2):

Please check if you have *Do not wrap* in your styling for method calls with arguments.
You can check under: code style -> java -> Wrapping and Braces -> Method call arguments -> Do not wrap.
You can change this to *Wrap if long* and adjust additional styling if required.

[image]

Comment: I tried different combinations of this to no avail.

Comment: Are you sure that the statement hits the margin at 80? Try reducing it to 60 or 40 and hitting `Ctrl+Alt+L` while in the Editor to trigger reformatting.